# Is this function rational?

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Let
$$
F=\sum_{i\ge0}\frac1{(T+2)^i}\left(\frac T{T+1}\right)^{3^i}\in\mathbb F_3\left(\!\!\left(\frac1T\right)\!\!\right).$$
Does $F$ belong to $\mathbb F_3(T)$?
Here, truncations of the series  do not give a good approximation of $F$.

Comment: Are $n$ and $i$ the same? Does $\mathbb{F}_3((1/T))$ mean the ring of power series in $1/T$?

Comment: Yes for both. I edited the question.

Comment: does it converge?

Comment: sure, since $\deg\left(\frac1{(T+2)^i}\left(\frac T{T+1}\right)^{3^i}\right)=-i\underset{i\to+\infty}{\to}-\infty$.

Comment: I see, you are right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not rational.

First of all we denote $1/T=x$, then $$F=\sum_i \left(\frac{x}{1+2x}\right)^i(1+x)^{-3^i}\in \mathbb{F}_3((x)).$$
Now denote $x/(1+2x)=y$. Note that rationality in $x$ is equivalent to rationality in $y$ (and also that $\mathbb{F}_3((x))=\mathbb{F}_3((y))$). We have $x=y/(1-2y)$; $1+x=(1-y)/(1-2y)$; $$(1+x)^{-1}=\frac{1-2y}{1-y}=\frac{1+y}{1-y}=1-(y+y^2+y^3+\ldots).$$
Thus $$F=\sum_i y^i(1-y^{3^i}-y^{2\cdot 3^i}-\ldots)=\frac1{1-y}-\sum_{i\geqslant 0, k\geqslant 1}y^{i+k\cdot 3^i}.$$We should prove that the sequence of coefficients $a_n$ of the power series $$\sum_{i\geqslant 0, k\geqslant 1}y^{i+k\cdot 3^i}=\sum a_ny^n$$
is not eventually periodic modulo 3 (since rationality of a power series with coefficients in a finite field is equivalent to eventual periodicity of its coefficients).

We have $a_n=|A(n)|$, where $A(n)$ is the set of all non-negative integers $i<n$, for which $3^i$ divides $n-i$. It is straightforward that $A(k)=A(k+3^{k-1})$ for all $k>1$ and $A(k+3^{n-1})=A(k)\sqcup \{k\}$ for all $n>k>1$. This yields $a_{k+3^{k-1}}=a_k$ and $a_{k+3^{n-1}}=a_k+1$ for all $n>k>1$.

Now assume that, on the contrary, $a_{n+T}\equiv a_{n} \pmod 3$ for certain integer $T>0$ and all $n\geqslant n_0$. Consider the powers of 3 of the form $3^{m-1}$, $m>n_0$. By pigeonhole principle, there exist two of them which are congruent modulo $T$, say, $T$ divides $3^{n-1}-3^{k-1}$ for certain $n>k>n_0$. Then $T$ divides $(k+3^{n-1})-(k+3^{k-1})$ but from above we have $a_{k+3^{n-1}}=a_k+1=a_{k+3^{k-1}} +1$. This contradicts to our periodicity assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed proof. Just one thing: "since rationality of a power series with coefficients in a finite field is equivalent to eventual periodicity of its coefficients". Where can I find a proof of that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One side (periodicity yields rationality) is rather clear. For the other side, note that rationality is equivalent to a linear recurrence of the coefficients. But for any finite set $A$ any sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$ of elements of $A$ defined by the recurrence of the form "each element is a function of previous 100 elements" is eventually periodic: you may find two identical blocks of length 100 in this sequence, and it yields periodicity.

Comment: Thanks. It is very clear now.